# select2 with tags select automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 and all works fine.
Now I would like to create a select2 input field with the tag option:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.dropdown').val(null).trigger("change");

$('.dropdown').select2({
        language: "de",
        width: "100%",
        placeholder: '',
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>




<select class="dropdown" name="state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

My problem:
If you will type "Te" (for "Test") it will be automatically select the option "Alabama".
This should not be. Is this a bug or how can I solve this?

Comment: **Side note:** OP wants to create new tags if they don't exist in the dropdown.